# Find and Replace using different keywords

Tags: text-editing, find-and-replace, notepad

Example. I want to find and replace using:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
```

Of course I have to input and click it 3 times in order for me to find and replace using those terms. How do I do it in one shot?

Does it work with:

```
class="tbc" 
class="tbd" 
class="tbc-r" 
class="tbd-r" 
class="tbd-c" 
class="tbc-r" 
class="tbh" 
class="tbsh"
```

Comment: What do you want to happen here? Do "Test1", "Test2" and "Test3" all get replaced by the same string or different strings?

Comment: for example there is this one file that contains "Test1", "Test2" and "Test3", i want to get rid of them in one click..

Answer (score 3):

Notepad doesn't support wildcards (let alone regular expressions) in its text substitution process.

So, no, there is no easier and/or faster way than emitting 3 instructions.

If you're allowed to look into alternatives, you might be able to achieve what you're looking for by using the free text editor [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Here I made a quick example that uses a simple regular expression `Test\d` to match the lines in that file.
[image]
Then I just click *Replace All* and removed all occurrences in one go:
[image]

I hope that's what you're looking for.

---

For completeness sake, this is the regular expression which I sent you via email to match your `class=` parts:

```
class="[^"]*"
```

Comment: can you recomment any software that could do it?

Comment: what im trying to do is find and replace using different keywords in one file. What i want is to remove it by clicking one..

Comment: [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a very popular, free text editor that has extensive text replacement support. Most likely, you'll be able to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, I thought I've understood what you want to achieve, but I haven't. Please explain it in more detail in your question.

Comment: for example there is this one file that contains "Test1", "Test2" and "Test3", i want to get rid of them in one click.. 

i just need a text editor that can find and replace using multiple keywords

Comment: I added an example for you into my answer. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/) will of course do this, as any other text editing task you can imagine. The problem is that it may take a while to learn if you never used it.

Anyway, this is how:

```
:%s/Test1\|Test2\|Test3//g
```

It's search and replace using regexp. The part between the first and second `/`, is the search string and between second and last the replacement string (in this case empty).