# Removing HTML tags in Notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++, find-and-replace, tags

I'm trying to remove some tags using the Find and Replace feature of Notepad++.

What I'm trying to remove for example is `<num>` and `</num>`. Right now I'd input `<num>` and replace it, then input `</num>` and replace that.

How can I do this in one shot?

[Here](https://superuser.com/q/399795/48078) I already found out how to remove `class="???"`.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to remove `< num >` and not `<num>`?

Comment: <num> is valid html, < num > would not work (at least not in modern browsers.

Comment: Rolled back. Sifr87, please check your formatting next time – it was right all along.

Answer (score 3):

use the regex option and input `</?num>`

Comment: mark it solved so ratchet freak can get points then, please

Comment: @conspiritech Sifr87 will also get some reputation. :)